# Transition СSS последовательное применение в обратном порядке

Tags: html, css, css3

Как воиспрозвести [данный переход](http://jsfiddle.net/QNCmu/5/) при отменее фокуса в обратном порядке

```
input {
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-transition-property: border-radius, width;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.2s;
}

input:focus {
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

ТО есть при снятии фокуса сначал меняется ширина а потом уже border-radius
Кстати если указать border-radius изначально в px работает лучше, но не все равно не совсем так

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример в обратном порядке:

```css
    input {
        width: 50px;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        outline: none;
        animation-duration:0s;
        border: 1px solid red;
        -webkit-transition-property: width, border-radius;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
        -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0s;
        animation-iteration-count:1;
    }
    input:focus {
        width: 300px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-transition-property: border-radius, width;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: без анимации нужно

Comment: @ruslik не понял вас

Comment: без animation(без анимации, просто переходы transtition)

Comment: @ruslik так нормально ?

Comment: для чего используется animation-duration:0s; animation-iteration-count:1;

Comment: @ruslik посмотрите тут, или можете гуглить в другом сайте посмотреть
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-duration.asp, https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-iteration-count.asp

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nvn6p/1/ - посмотрите вот это пример, он без анимации

Comment: но почему то в моем случае не работает

Comment: Я же дал пример без анимации.

Comment: мы наверно не понимаем друг друга,  в моем понимании анимация(animation) и переходы(transition)  - это разные понятия

Comment: @rusik Переход (`transition`) - это анимация, только одна из которых выполняется между двумя различными состояниями, то есть начальным состоянием и конечным состоянием.